# set vary header in tomcat web server?

Tags: tomcat, header, vary

how i can specify vary header in tomcat?
what's the difference between vary header:user agent and vary header:accept encoding.
i just enabled Gzip compression in tomcat for .XHR format file.but it didn't work.
i used this MIME type:

```
compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,
                text/javascript,text/json,application/x-javascript,
                application/javascript,application/json,
                text/x-javascript,text/x-json,
               'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
               'text/plain; charset=x-user-defined'"
```